# post content to facebook to users' wall?

Tags: facebook, share

i've built a survey and at the end i want the users to share their result on their facebook wall but i'm finding it hard to find any examples or reference.

something like;

```
<div>
[ image/graphic ] 
"I've just completed survey XXX and got 90%"
<a>post on my wall</a>
</div>
```

any help appreciated - even if its just terminology i can look up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web).  Basically, you're creating a website which you want to integrate into Facebook.  To do so, your users will need to "login to Facebook" from your site (unless they're already logged in, such as in another browser tab) and allow your site to perform certain actions on Facebook on their behalf.

The [Single Sign-On](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login) part is where you will initialize your website as a Facebook application (you'll need to create the application on Facebook first) and provide a login button for your users.

Your login button can be set up to ask the user for [specific permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) to act on their behalf with Facebook.  I think the one you want is `publish-stream` but I'm only barely familiar with it, play around with the functionality and see what works best for you.  Your users will be presented with a pop-up div stating that your website (or application) is requesting these specific permissions and they have the option to allow or deny.  An example can be seen [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#registration).

Once you have the user's permission, you make use of the cookie (demonstrated using PHP back on the Single Sign-On link) to gain access to information by use of the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api), the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), [Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/plugins), etc.

Comment: thanks - eventually got something going but still having probs with images (randomly works sometimes). This was a great help too; http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: @daniel Crabbe: Nice link, I hadn't seen that before.  The next time I engage in any kind of Facebook development (so far it's just been tinkering, no real projects) I'll be sure and use it.  Thanks!

Comment: yeh - started off ok but having probs with validation now on the meta tags' propert attr... will post solution if found!

Answer (score 1):

you should use the facebook api.

Get the "publish_stream" right of a user and use the "api" method of the connection object (with parameters like : '/userid/feed', 'post', array of informations about the post).

I can't find the right code and the official document is not always up-to-date.

OR

Just add a facebook "share" button on your page that uses "meta" markups. You should find examples on about 80% of websites.